# How do i get to next form in visual basic

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get to the next form for my Excel macro.

Right now, I have a login form that has the user name and password
that works. When I press login, it goes to next form.

But, when I go to my next form and type the information in it, it closes and doesn't pull up the next forum.

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong? Why won't my next form pop up?

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

                     

'Dim iRow As Long
'Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("D544 Back Panel")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'check for a part number
   If Trim(Me.txtPrd.Value) = "" Then
  Me.txtPrd.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please enter a Production Number"
  Exit Sub
End If

'copy the data to the database
'use protect and unprotect lines,
'     with your password
'     if worksheet is protected
With ws
'  .Unprotect Password:="Password"

  .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.txtDate.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.txtHrs.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.txtPrd.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.txtSrp.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.txtOper.Value

'  .Protect Password:="Password"
End With

'clear the data
Me.txtDate.Value = ""
Me.txtHrs.Value = ""
Me.txtPrd.Value = ""
Me.txtSrp.Value = ""
Me.txtOper.Value = ""
Me.txtPrd.SetFocus

Unload Me




    

End Sub


Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
 
'Dim iRow As Long
'Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Scrap")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'check for a part number
If Trim(Me.txtPress.Value) = "" Then
  Me.txtPress.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please enter press scrap"
  Exit Sub
End If

'copy the data to the database
'use protect and unprotect lines,
'     with your password
'     if worksheet is protected
With ws
'  .Unprotect Password:="Password"

  .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.txtDelam.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.txtCuts.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.txtBurns.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.txtDents.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.txtStaple.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.txtGlue.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.txtPress.Value
  
'  .Protect Password:="Password"
End With

'clear the data
Me.txtDelam.Value = ""
Me.txtCuts.Value = ""
Me.txtBurns.Value = ""
Me.txtDents.Value = ""
Me.txtStaple.Value = ""
Me.txtGlue.Value = ""
Me.txtPress.Value = ""
Me.txtPress.SetFocus
Unload Me



End Sub
```

Comment: Please add the code you are using. It's next-to-impossible to troubleshoot code, sight-unseen.

Comment: How does your form "Close" after typing information in? Does your form contain code to open up the "Next Form". How is the "Next Form" determined as forms don't have an inherent ordering? How does the login form do it properly? I think all of these questions could be answered if you posted the code behind these, otherwise we are even more lost than you.

Comment: sorry about that. here is code...

Comment: I have re posted...

Comment: From your description, it sounds like the are three forms: login(1) , information_add(2), un-described(3). Is this the code for your second form? Where is the code which calls the third form?

Comment: yes information(3)

Comment: information add 3 to a separate work sheet

Comment: I don't see any code which calls the third form. Do you call the third form anywhere? if so, please show that code as well.

Comment: I figured out that to go to the next I used Formname1.hide and Formname2.Show that worked to bring that next form up. I am now having trouble with submitting my 3rd from to my excel sheet. I will post that code

Comment: I have edited to show my third form code

Comment: @Broc I think it's great that you were able to solve your initial issue yourself! Since part of the goal of this website is to also be a resource for other people stuck on similar issues, it'd be preferred if you could post the answer you found to this stated problem. Then, for your new issue, post a new question with a relevant question title. Thank you!

Comment: @Mistella I am very new to this so I apologize!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I used 
    Formname1.Hide
    Formname2.Show

This seemed to solve my issue. Thanks for the help guys. Sorry I am very new to this site.